# Blazor Custom Authentication - NotAuthorized showing before Authorized

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm relatively new to Blazor and have created custom log-in authentication for a Blazor Server app. After logging in, it directs to an index page. While everything appears to work, there is a brief period on the loading of the page where it seems to load the NotAuthorized component first, then quickly loads the Authorized component view. I'm honestly stumped. Shouldn't only the correct authorized view load, not one and then the other? I have included the applicable code below.

The @code from my login component:

```html
private async Task Authenticate()
    {
        IsLoading = true;
        StateHasChanged();
        string userAccount = await userAccountSerivce.GetUser(UserName, Password);
        if (userAccount == null)
        {
            IsLoading = false;
        }
        else if (userAccount == "locked")
        {
            IsLoading = false;
            await js.InvokeVoidAsync("alert", "User account is currently locked out.");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            var customAuthStateProvider = (CustomAuthentication)authStateProvider;
            await customAuthStateProvider.UpdateAuthenticationState(new UserSession
                {
                    UserName = UserName,
                    Role = "User"
                });
            navManager.NavigateTo("/index", true);
        }
    }
```

My CustomAuthentication.cs code:

```html
namespace FAApp_Server.Authentication
{
    public class CustomAuthentication : AuthenticationStateProvider
    {

        private readonly ProtectedSessionStorage _sessionStorage;
        private ClaimsPrincipal _anonymous = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity());

        public CustomAuthentication(ProtectedSessionStorage sessionStorage)
        {
            _sessionStorage = sessionStorage;
        }

        public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                var userSessionStorageResult = await _sessionStorage.GetAsync<UserSession>("UserSession");
                var userSession = userSessionStorageResult.Success ? userSessionStorageResult.Value : null;

                if (userSession == null)
                {
                    return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(_anonymous));
                }

                var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userSession.UserName),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userSession.Role),
            }, "CustomAuth"));
                return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(claimsPrincipal));
            }
            catch
            {
                return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(_anonymous));
            }
        }

        public async Task UpdateAuthenticationState(UserSession userSession)
        {
            ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal;

            if (userSession != null)
            {
                await _sessionStorage.SetAsync("UserSession", userSession);
                claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userSession.UserName),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userSession.Role)
                }));
            }
            else
            {
                await _sessionStorage.DeleteAsync("UserSession");
                claimsPrincipal = _anonymous;
            }

            NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(claimsPrincipal)));
        }
    }
}
```

My index component:

```html
@page "/index"

@inject NavigationManager navManager

<PageHeader Header="Test Site"></PageHeader>
<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        <h2 style="text-align:center;padding-top:5%">Welcome, @username!</h2><br />
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <h1 style="text-align:center;padding-top:5%">User session has ended. Please <a href="/">login</a>.</h1>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>

@code{
    [CascadingParameter]
    private Task<AuthenticationState> authenticationState { get; set; }
    private String username { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var authState = await authenticationState;
        username = authState.User.Identity.Name;
    }

}
```